# What is the fastest way to calculate min, max, mean, median and standard deviation from C# array?

Tags: c#, max, mean, min, standard-deviation

I have a larger array or list of doubles which is not sorted and I want to calculate min, max, mean, median and standard deviation the most efficient way. Of course I could simply use Linq to calculate each one by one, but I think one can go faster. Sample code:

```
var list = new List<double>(){1.0, 2.5, 0.11, 0.7, 8.2, 3.4, 1.0};
var (min, max, mean, median, std) = CalculateMetrics(list);

private (double, double, double, double, double) CalculateMetrics(List<double> list) {
    // TODO
}
```

So what is the most efficient way? Using libraries is also fine for me.

Comment: when you say "larger", like how large? 500? 5k? 5M? 5B? If you have an estimate of your potential array size, you can select a better algorithm. It might not be necessary to do a lot of optimization for a primitive array of size around 1k, considering all the overhead associated.

Answer (score 3):

All the descriptive stats *except median* you want can be computed in one pass through your `list`. The trick to getting the standard deviation is accumulating both the sum and the sum-of-squares of your samples. Here's an example of that.

```cs
int count = 0;
double sum = 0.0;
double sumsq = 0.0;
double max = double.MinValue;
double min = double.MaxValue;

foreach (double sample in list)
{
    count++;
    sum += sample;
    sumsq += sample * sample;
    if (sample > max) max = sample;
    if (sample < min) min = sample;
}

double mean = sum / count;
double stdev = Math.Sqrt((sumsq / count) - (mean * mean));
```

Because this makes only one pass through the list, it works with any `IEnumerable` collection of samples, and is compatible with LINQ.

Obviously this is quick-n-dirty example code. I leave it to you to build it into a useful function.

It will throw a divide check on an empty `list`.  And, if you have very large numbers or very long lists, that subtraction in the computation of `stdev` may lose precision and give you back a useless number.

But it works well for most applications.

Comment: OP wants median also, for which the list needs to be sorted to do it in `O(n)`

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed the median requirement. So much for the single pass **O(n)** unless the list is known *a priori* to be sorted, as you mention. You may as well use `list.Median()` to get the median; it's decently optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Because the median is asked for and the standard deviation requires the mean, it makes this hard to do in O(n).

Here's my best attempt:

```
private (double min, double max, double mean, double median, double std) CalculateMetrics(List<double> list)
{
    var mean = list.Average();
    var std = Math.Sqrt(list.Aggregate(0.0, (a, x) => a + (x - mean) * (x - mean)) / list.Count());
    var sorted = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    var median = sorted.Count % 2 == 0 ? (sorted[sorted.Count / 2 - 1] + sorted[sorted.Count / 2]) / 2 : sorted[sorted.Count / 2];
    return (sorted.First(), sorted.Last(), mean, median, std);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O(2n) solution:

```cs
        private static (double, double, double, double, double) CalculateMetrics(double[] list)
        {
            if (list.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            double min = list[0];
            double max = list[0];
            double median = list[list.Length / 2];

            double sum = 0;
            foreach (double el in list)
            {
                if (el > max)
                {
                    max = el;
                }
                if (el < min)
                {
                    min = el;
                }

                sum += el;
            }

            double mean = sum / list.Length;

            double sumStd = 0;
            foreach (var el in list)
            {
                sumStd += Math.Pow(el - mean, 2) / list.Length;
            }
            double stdDev = Math.Sqrt(sumStd);

            return (min, max, mean, median, stdDev);
        }
```

Comment: there is no median calculation here (list had to be sorted)

Comment: Apart from requiring a sorted list, the median is defined as the average of the middle two if the list is of even length.